# How can I transform a chr variable into num?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 148 observations, and there's a variable (gender) that is in chr format with characters "M" and "F" for male and female, respectively. I want to transform those "M"s and "F"s into "1"s and "2"s to work with them.

I tried running the following regression:

```
m0 <- lm(log(cleandata2$salary) ~ cleandata2$gender)
summary(m0)
```

but the summary only showed results for M:

```
Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        12.46716    0.03496 356.571   <2e-16 ***
cleandata2$genderM  0.10440    0.04254   2.454   0.0153 *
```

I want the regression to include genderF as well.

Comment: Look at `plyr::mapvalues()` for one easy way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it belongs on the stats site of Stack Overflow.  Your statement "I want the regression to include genderF as well." indicates you could use some help understanding the regression estimates.  In short, both genders are represented in that table (sometimes called an 'anova table).  The second row is the offset of males (compared to females, which are the "reference level").

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
cleandata2$gender <- factor(cleandata2$gender, 
                 levels=c('M', 'F'), 
                 labels=c(1, 2))
```